# Shuffling an array when entering a view

Tags: swiftui

I am building a simple game that displays a set of shuffled cards

To do this, I have an array which I would like to shuffle everytime the user enters the GameView. The set of numbers generated will be traversed to show cards it that order (to eliminate showing the same card twice in a row - if I were to pick a random index)

I have a menuView and a gameView. I would like to shuffle the array everytime the user enters the gameView.

As it is now - if the users enters the gameView - they are shown a set of shuffled cards - which is fine.

However, if they navigate back to the menuView and again enter the gameView - it shows them in the same order. I would like to shuffle the cards to start a new game.

This is my MenuView

```
struct MenuView: View {
   
    @State var sequence = (0..<cardArray.count).shuffled()

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {                
                VStack{
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    MainTitle(text: "TITLE")
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        sequence = (0..<cardArray.count).shuffled()
                        GameView(sequence: $sequence)
                    }, label: {
                        PrimaryButton(text: "PLAY")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my gameView

```
struct GameView: View {  
    @Binding var sequence: [Int]
    @State var cardNumber = 0  
    var body: some View {  
        ZStack {
            BackgroundComponent()
            
            VStack
            {
                CardComponent(cardDifficulty: cardArray[sequence[cardNumber]].difficulty)  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding the code shuffle the array within the .onAppear() of the menuView - and that seems to work - but was wondering if this is fine or if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

How I can running the shuffle code everytime I enter into GameView?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by enter/access the view?

Comment: As in transitioning into the GameView - which is a seperate screen

Comment: `onAppear` is for the rescue, like you already discovered. Also IMO good point to introduce a view model, since game of cards is probably not just a couple of @States.

Comment: Thanks timbre timbre, do you mind expanding on what you mean by that? Do you mean a a swift file that handles parameters for the game? if so, how would  parameters within the view model 'talk' to the the other views ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way - you should shuffle cards in `GameView .onAppear()`, not in `MenuView .onAppear()`.

Update `MenuView` as below:

```
struct MenuView: View {
   
    @State var sequence: [Int] = [] // No need for shuffling during initialization.

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {                
                VStack{
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    MainTitle(text: "TITLE")
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        // sequence = (0..<cardArray.count).shuffled() <- remove this line
                        GameView(sequence: $sequence)
                    }, label: {
                        PrimaryButton(text: "PLAY")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update `GameView` as below:

```
struct GameView: View {  
    @Binding var sequence: [Int]
    @State var cardNumber = 0  
    var body: some View {  
        ZStack {
            BackgroundComponent()
            
            VStack
            {
                CardComponent(cardDifficulty: cardArray[sequence[cardNumber]].difficulty)  
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            sequence = (0..<cardArray.count).shuffled() // Shuffle cards in GameView
        }
    }
}
```

You have used `@State` and `@Binding` in code. So the sequence variable is updated in `MenuView` once the sequence is modified in `GameView`. There is no need to 'talk' to `MenuView`.

If you still wondering, you can add the code below in `MenuView`. It will help you understand this mechanism.

```
struct MenuView: View {
    // ...
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {                
                // ..
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("sequence: \(sequence)") // add this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks KerryDong.

I guess if I include it in the GameView, then I probabl don't need it at all in the MenuView and get rid of the $Binding parameter?

Comment: Sure! You can remove it if you don't need to be notified of changes in the sequence variable in MenuView.